# How I can play music background on IOS app using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm building my first ios app, and I want play mp3 file when app start run and when I change the page it still play not reload to start play.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 4.0 and above you can run audio in the background. PhoneGap doesn't currently support this out of the box, but you can add it. To do so, you'll need to do two things; add an item to the info.plist file and add a line of code to PhoneGap.

To the info.plist file, add a new key of “Required background modes”. That key will have an array of options. In “Item 0” of that array set the value to “App plays audio”.

Next, modify the ~/PhoneGapLib/Classes/Sound.m file. Look for the line that contains “if ([resourceURL isFileURL]) {”. It's around line 103. Just below that line, inside the if statement, you'll want to add the following.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

So, that section of code will look like the following.

```
if ([resourceURL isFileURL]) {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    audioFile.player = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:resourceURL error:&error];
} else {
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:resourceURL];
    audioFile.player = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithData:data error:&error];
}
```

Note: Some users have have had trouble finding the Sound.m file. It's not in the XCode project itself. You'll find it beneath your home directory (~) under ~/PhoneGapLib/Classes/ or you can just use Finder to search for Sound.m. Right-click on it and open it in XCode.

Comment: Thanks I done thing above, but I don't know how to play mp3 file, where to put mp3 file. I'm a baby with ios app. Please help me.

Comment: which tool you are using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode and building with phonegap. I added before code like you instruct, but now for example I want to play background mp3 file: abc.mp3. Where I start call this file to play. Sorry because of I'm doing with the first ios app. Please help me!